# latitude,longitude and address retrieve

Tags: mapkit

Hi all 
I know the barname,city name and country.I want to know the address,lat,long of the bar.Please help me how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the yahoo api for that

http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/

after gettin ur api key u can query like

http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=`"youtCountryorCity"`&appid=`"yourAppid"`